# Need help expressing column in an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, excel

while writing an algorithm dealing with excel data

if we want to compare each cell in a row we write

1. foreach row
2. foreach cell in a row
3. jf ( cell.value > 100 )

but if we dont want to compare each cell in the row but only the cells of a particular collumn

then do we write like this ?

1. foreach row
2. if ( particular_collumn.cell.value > 100 )

or is there a better way to express this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is pseudocode.

It looks OK, but I would emphasise the fact that the particular column was used to reference the cell in the row. IOW, something like this:

1. foreach row
2. if ([cell at particular_column of row].value > 100 )

...

K.

Answer (score 1):

foreach specified_column
 foreach cell in a column
 jf ( cell.value > 100 )

Comment: that would check up all the cells of the excel document i want all cells of a particular collumn to be checked

Answer (score 0):

```
$column_to_use = 7;
for ($i=0;$i++;$i<$column_to_use) {
    // do magic here
}
```

Seriously, silverkid, it's not rocket science ;)

Comment: my question was actually that does "particular_collumn.cell.value " looks good to write while wrinting an algorithm  or not

Comment: and it was an EXCEL question.

Comment: Pavium ... he told us about his excel file and "algorithms". Could be very much every language out there, including brainfuck and the Shakespeare Programming Language.